# Maximum Client IP Length

Tags: php, networking

When storing a client's IP in `long` form (using PHP's `ip2long`) how large does the database field have to be?

Answer (score 2):

4 bytes (assuming IPv4). That is all that is required.

**EDIT**

If you want to store IPv8 you need 16 bytes. You can use the mechanism as described on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6 to differentiate between the two

Comment: Doesn't `ip2long` only work on IPv4 addresses? I'm looking at the PHP manual and it seems to have an example of `ip2long` returning `3221234342`, that is 10 bytes, isn't it?

Comment: @JordanDoyle - That is why I added "(assuming IPv4)"

Answer (score 1):

```
15 characters for IPv4 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format, 12+3 separators)
39 characters (32 + 7 separators) for IPv6
```

8 groups of 4 digits with 7 ':' between them

So that is

```
(8*4)+7=39
```

or If consider **IPv4**

```
[0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:192.168.0.1]
```

then

```
(6 * 4 + 5) + 1 + (4 * 3 + 3) = 29 + 1 + 15 = 45
```

Or as jordan said 
You can also store the IP addr like this

```
INSERT table(ip) VALUES (INET_ATON('192.168.0.1')); /*ip = 3232235521*/
SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) As IPAddress FROM table;
```

Comment: He's converting the IP address to an int using `ip2long()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Comment: What about when the IP is in `long` form such as `3221234342`? EDIT: Looks like Adam beat me to it

Comment: @JordanDoyle chk my updated answer